# generator-angular-fullstack and UI Router resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I used the [generator-angular-fullstack](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) to create an Angular 1.6 application and I can't get the value of my resolve in UI Router.

**I tried to use it like this:**

*Route:*

```
$stateProvider.state('main', {
  url: '/',
  template: '<main></main>',
  resolve: {
    test: function() { return 'test' }
  }
});
```

*Controller*

```
constructor($state, socket, localStorageService, test) {
}
```

Which lead to an `unknow provider` error.

**And this way:**

*Route:*

```
$stateProvider.state('main', {
  url: '/',
  template: '<main test="$resolve.test"></main>',
  resolve: {
    test: function() {
      return 'test'
    }
  }
});
```

*Component:*

```
component('main', {
  template: require('./main.pug'),
  bindings: {
    test: '='
  },
  controller: MainController
})
```

*Controller:*

```
constructor($state, socket, localStorageService) {
  console.log(this.test)
}
```

And the value of this.test is always `Undefined`, no mater what I do.

What am I missing ? It seem to work for everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. If anyone is having the same issue, it's because the second method work in Angular 1.5 but in Angular 1.6 you have to access the resolved variable in the $onInit method and not in the constructor directly.

Here is an update that work correctly:

```
constructor($state, socket, localStorageService) {
}

$onInit() {
  console.log(this.test)
}
```